# Facebook Messenger Bot - generic template default action not supporting messenger extensions

Tags: facebook, facebook-messenger, facebook-messenger-bot

I am sending the bot the following data. The template is rendered properly, but Messenger Extensions only work when I use the Go button, but the default_action lacks support for Messenger Extensions and I get an error message saying that current version of the SDK doesn't support Messenger Extensions and that I should upgrade, but as stated above, using the Go button works well. How to get Messenger Extensions working with default action?

```
{
  "recipient": {
    "id": *recipientId*
  },
  "message": {
    "attachment": {
      "type": "template",
      "payload": {
        "template_type": "generic",
        "elements": [
          {
            "title": "*Title*",
            "image_url": "*ImageUrl*",
            "subtitle": "*Subtitle*",
            "buttons": [
              {
                "type": "web_url",
                "url": "*TheUrl*",
                "title": "Go",
                "messenger_extensions": true,
                "fallback_url": "*TheUrl*"
              },
              {
                "type": "element_share"
              }
            ],
            "default_action": {
              "type": "web_url",
              "url": "*TheUrl*",
              "messenger_extensions": true,
              "fallback_url": "*TheUrl*"
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}
```